Api Handler de nextjs devuelve 404 en produccion y en local funciona
Tengo un problema un poco extraño, tengo una app desplegada en EC2 AWS, utilizando Nextjs version 14 app router.
Cuando hago una petición utilizando API folder en mi entorno local funciona correctamente.
En producción obtengo un error 404 not found.
Estoy seguro de que mis ENV están correctas, pero solo me sucede con el api router.
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const response = await fetch('/api/guatecompras/by-user', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
        }
        const data = await response.json();

        if (data) {
          const categories = data.categoria.map((cat: any) => cat.categoria);
          const keywords = data['temas-interes'].join(', ');
          const emails = data.correos.join(', ');

          setValue('categorias', categories);
          setValue('keywords', keywords);
          setValue('emails', emails);
        }
      } catch (error: any) {
        setError(error.message);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [setValue]);

Mi handler se ve así:

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  try {
    const body: CreateCategoriasBotDto = await req.json();
    const data: GuatecomprasBot[] = await createCategoriasBot(body);
    return NextResponse.json(data);
  } catch (error: any) {
    return NextResponse.json({message: error.message}, {status: 500});
  }
}


